# Want to deploy WCF web service on Azure platform

Tags: wcf, azure-storage

I want to deploy my WCF web Service on Azure plateform.
I have created a Storage account for my website, and also created a cloud Service and uploaded my package file and config file to the staging site.
But while uploading, The message displays 
'Your staging deployment is starting. Hang on, the page will refresh once the deployment begins.'
I am waiting sice 2-3 hours and not getting the desired output.

Am I doing correctly? Or is there anything that I forgot?
Please Help...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there is a problem in your code or the packaging that is causing the role to continuously restart. This is a fairly common problem, but there are a lot of possible causes (missing an assembly reference, an uncaught exception, the Run() method is exiting, a Startup Task is failing, or many other things). You need to gather more information to know exactly what the problem is and how to fix it.

There are [many threads here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=azure%20role%20recycling%20loop) about this topic. There's also a [Microsoft post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh134844.aspx) discussing how to diagnose this type of issue. Those are good places to start.